# I want to retrieve data from firebase database for my Android app into a dropdown menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

This is my DashboarActvity where I want to display data using the spinners. I have tried some tutorials but most of them talk about list view. I want set values in a dropdown menu.

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Spinner spinnerUnion;
private Spinner spinnerMouja;
private Spinner spinnerRevenue;
private Spinner spinnerHoldingNumber;

private TextView textViewName;
private TextView textViewMoney;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private Button buttonSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    spinnerUnion = findViewById(R.id.spinnerUnion);
    spinnerMouja = findViewById(R.id.spinnerMouja);
    spinnerRevenue = findViewById(R.id.spinnerRevenue);
    spinnerHoldingNumber = findViewById(R.id.spinnerHoldingNumber);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    textViewName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewMoney = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewMoney);

    buttonSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
    buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(this);


}



@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    if(view == buttonSearch){

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Spinner spinnerUnion;
ArrayAdapter<String> sU;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    spinnerUnion = findViewById(R.id.spinnerUnion);

    sU = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot{
            sU.add(dataSnapshot.child("Your Field").getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    spinnerUnion.setAdapter(sU);

}
```